# Vertical space between a word and a line

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, line-spacing, cv

I want to reduce the vertical distance between "Education" and the line. How to do that?

I am using the following code:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*{\Line}[3][]{\tikz \draw[#1] #2 -- #3;}%
\textbf{Education}
\Line[black, thick]{(0,0)}{(6.99in,0)}%
```

Output (this is my current output but I want less vertical space between "Education" and the line):

[image]

Or may be I can use something else? I just want to have a thick line below "Education" section of my resume.

Comment: Do you like to have this line in text?  For TikZ picture this is unusualy approach, there is normally something as `\draw (0,0) node[above right] {\textbf{Education}} -- (6.99in,0);`  In a text is people normally use rule: `\rule[<lift>]{<thick>}{<length>}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two different ways to do the same thing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent\rlap{\textbf{Education}}\rule[-2pt]{\textwidth}{.5pt}

\noindent\underline{\makebox[\textwidth][l]{\textbf{Education}}}
\end{document}
```

[image: undeline]